# CSS Properties Extension

Tags: css, webkit

I am a web developer, I recently looked at GMAIL's new [LOGIN PAGE](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/?hl=en&tab=wm&ui=html&zy=l&bsv=llya694le36z&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&hl=en&from=login) preview and there is a Sign In button, I was really excited about its UI. I did some surgery of Page's CSS and found some properties like:

```
**background-color: #4D90FE;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4d90fe),to(#4787ed));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);**
```

Now can anyone please tell me how can I maximize the page's optimization for all popular browsers using these kind of CSS extension properties. I mean is there any reference link for these extensions or some other good stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a list that I keep on me all times as a point of reference.

I hope this is of some use to you

http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/general/webkit_css_styles

Comment: Rememeber to thank ;) Its one of the best links ive got for css3 properties :)

Comment: link is broken, please fix it

Answer (score 0):

You should use google to find such information, a lot of it has been around since early 2010.

but here are some examples of browser specific gradient codes:

```
.gradient-bg {
   /* fallback/image non-cover color */
   background-color: #1a82f7; 

   /* fallback image */
   background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png); 

   /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#2F2727), to(#1a82f7));

   /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7); 

   /* Firefox 3.6+ */
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

   /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}
```

Taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/5700-css3-gradients/).

Comment: Actually I tried it before taking stackoverflow step, but unable to find single resource where I can find complete lists for all major web browsers, however thanks for this information...

Answer (score 0):

To find out which browser supports which selector has a lot to with testing.

If you just need cross-browser-gradients, use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ (supports also IE6-9).

To find out, which technique is supported by which browser http://caniuse.com is a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty comprehensive list of Mozilla's CSS extensions (or simply things that haven't been fully standardized yet) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

There is also an attempt to list all vendor-specific CSS properties under http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-extensions.htm but it is probably pretty incomplete and outdated - this area changes fast. In the end, you should better look at [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css3). Either a feature is already listed there which means that vendor prefixes will likely be dropped soon - or it is not and then using this feature in a production webpage isn't recommendable (its meaning might change significantly or browsers might stop supporting it altogether).

Comment: ...and also here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions, though it's mostly a list with very little description behind it.